# Converting polar coordinate expression to cartesian coordinates

Tags: replacement

An intermediate step in my analysis requires me to work in polar coordinates, but I would like to convert the results back into cartesian coordinates. The conversion is very simple but tedious for complex expressions. I expected to use substitutions, but it isn't panning out for me

```
polarf[{r_, phi_}] := r^6 Sin[phi]^2 Cos[phi]^2
cartesianf[{k1_, k2_}] := 
 polarf[{r, phi}] /. r^2 Sin[phi]^2 -> k2^2 /. 
   r^2 Cos[phi]^2 -> k1^2 /. r^2 -> k1^2 + k2^2
cartesianf[{k1, k2}]
```

gives me back my original expression:

```
r^6 Cos[phi]^2 Sin[phi]^2
```

I'm pretty sure there is a way to get Mathematica to spit out

```
(k1^2 + k2^2) k1^2 k2^2
```

or something similar. But how? My searches of Google, Mathematica documentation, and this site have not turned up an answer.

Comment: I don't know if it solves your problem, but are you aware of `CoordinatesToCartesian` and `CoordinatesFromCartesian`?

Comment: It came up in my searches, but appears to transform point coordinates rather than functions of coordinates.

Comment: Is there a reason why you use replacement rules instead of simply inserting the formulas directly? That is, `cartesianf[{k1_,k2_}] := polarf[{Sqrt[k1^2+k2^2],ArcTan[k1,k2]}]` (however you then need a `FullSimplify` to arrive at the form you want: `FullSimplify[cartesianf[{k1,k2}]]`)

Comment: If you want to use replacement rules, you probably should first get rid of `phi`, then of `r`: `polarf[{r, phi}] /. { Cos[phi] -> k1/r, Sin[phi] -> k2/r } /. { r -> Sqrt[k1^2+k2^2] }`. Then you also don't need `FullSimplify`.

Comment: That works quite well in my sample code, but threw up warnings when used for my actual result. After a few minutes I aborted the evaluation.

Comment: @James: Which one?

Comment: Looks like you forgot a factor of `Abs[Sqrt[k2^2/(k1^2 + k2^2)]/k2]`?

Comment: @celtschk
my earlier reply was to your first reply. When I use that formulation I get this error  

    Integrate::ilim: "Invalid integration variable or limit(s) in {Sqrt[k1^2+k2^2],0,\[Infinity]}."  

    Reduce::fexp: Warning: Reduce used FunctionExpand to transform the system. Since FunctionExpand transformation rules are only generically correct, the solution set might have been altered.

Comment: @celtschk the second method does work, thank you. I did not think to remove the variables one at a time, but it was far more successful.

Comment: Could first get rid of trigs, then get rid of r. polarf[{r,phi}] /. {Sin[phi]->y/r,Cos[phi]->x/r}/.r->Sqrt[x^2+y^2] Or can do both at once. polarf[{r,phi}] /. {phi->ArcTan[y/x],r->Sqrt[x^2+y^2]}

Comment: @DanielLichtblau: You want `ArcTan[x,y]`, not `ArcTan[y/x]`, or else you get wrong values for negative `x`.

Answer (score 5):

You obviously misunderstand replacement rules. Replacement rules work on the structure level, and don't care about the mathematical meaning (they *do* take into accounts attributes like `Orderless`, however). In your case, you are saying with your first replacement rule that whereever your result contains the *structure* (more exactly, the pattern) `r^2 Sin[phi]^2` (that is, `Times[Power[r, 2], Power[Sin[phi], 2]]`), you want that replaced with the expression `k2^2`. However the result of your function does not contain this structure. It contains `r^6 Sin[phi]^2` which doesn't match your pattern because `6` is not `2`. For the same reason, your second replacement rule doesn't do anything, either.

What does work is

```
polarf[{r, phi}] /. { Cos[phi] -> k1/r, Sin[phi] -> k2/r } /.
                    { r -> Sqrt[k1^2 + k2^2] }
```

This works because the expression generated by `polarf`, `r^6 Cos[phi]^2 Sin[phi]^2`, *does* contain `Cos[phi]` and `Sin[phi]`, which in the first step get replaced by `k1/r` and `k2/r`. Thus you get `r^6 (k1/r)^2 (k2/r)^2` which gets further evaluated to `r^2 k1^2 k2^2`. Now the last replacement rule kicks in, replacing `r` by `Sqrt[k1^2 + k2^2]`. Thus you get `Sqrt[k1^2 + k2^2]^2 k1^2 k2^2` which evaluates to `(k1^2 + k2^2) k1^2 k2^2`, which is the expression you want.